# This error or keeps showing: integrityError,UNIQUE constraint failed: blog_post.author_id

Tags: python, django

Please can someone help me out fix this bug in my code.

This  is my code in the models.py files

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author=models.OneToOneField(User)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    article =models.TextField()
    publish_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug=models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

This is the code in views.py file

```
def add_post(request):
   if not  request.user.is_authenticated():
       return redirect('/login/')
   if request.method=='POST':
       form= post_form(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           post=form.save(commit=False)
           post.author=request.user
           post.slug=slugify(post.topic)
           form.save()
           slug=slugify(topic)
           return redirect('blog.views.post',slug=post.slug)
       else:
           return render(request,'post_add.html',{'form':form})
   else:
       form=post_form()
       template='post_add.html'
       return render (request,template,{'form':form})
```

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: You might already have an entry in your Post model with that user you are trying to add again.

So look into the Post table entries to make sure you are not repeating !!

Comment: You probably need a ForeignKey instead of OneToOne. As an author can have multiple posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You currently have a one to one field for author. That means that each post has one author, and each author can have at most one post. You are getting the error when you try to add a second post that has the same author.

Instead, you should use a foreign key. That means that each post will have one author, but multiple posts can be linked to the same author.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author=models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Once you have made this change, you will have to create a new migration and migrate, to remove the unique constraint.